# Styling a specific post after hovering over it

Tags: php, jquery, css

### Background

My website is organised in a grid layout of four columns of divs. Each div is a container for a post and is a square of 200 x 200px. The title is a header at the bottom of the div and there is either an excerpt or a featured image above. Currently, if you click on either the excerpt text/featured image or the header, you will be taken to a page with that specific content.

### Problem

I saw [this codepen](https://codepen.io/noeldelgado/pen/PZJGLx), and I wanted to emulate the same effect (preferably without haml and scss). In any case, what I wanted was for each div post to have a certain background and border colour with just the header in the centre, then after a hover or touchend, move the header down, remove background and border colours and reveal either the excerpt or the featured image.

I tried doing this by creating a div above each post called the hoverzone. Hovering over the zone would then change that div's class from post to post-hover with it's own separate styling. I got this to work except it would only change the first post's styling.

Because of Wordpress's loop, *all posts* have the same class and ID, i.e. 'post' and 'uniquepost' respectively.

**Is there a way to do a targeted selection of a specific post and change that post's style only during a hover or after a touchend?**

I tried using php with the class: hoverzone_<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>, only to realise that this could not be integrated into either JQuery nor CSS.

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this question is related to WordPress, but you should be able to accomplish what you're after with just CSS as demonstrated in the following [Codepen](https://codepen.io/NathanDJohnson/full/ZqjGJo/).

In case something happens to that, the code is copied here.

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a href="#">
    <article class="has-featured-image">
      <div class="post-title">Title</div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">This is an example excerpt. It is two sentences.</div>
      <div class="featured-image">
        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
      </div>
    </article>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <article>
      <div class="post-title">Title</div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">This is an example excerpt. It is two sentences.</div>
    </article>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <article>
      <div class="post-title">Title</div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">This is an example excerpt. It is two sentences.</div>
    </article>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <article>
      <div class="post-title">Title</div>
      <div class="post-excerpt">This is an example excerpt. It is two sentences.</div>
    </article>
  </a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
* {
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 500px;
}
article {
  background-color: #eee;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  color: #000;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0.125rem;
  max-height: 200px;
  max-width: 200px;
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 200px
}
article:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: initial;
  border-color: #fff;
}
.post-title {
  bottom: calc( 50% - 1rem );
  font-size: 2rem;
  left: calc( 50% - 2rem );
  max-width: calc( 100% - 3rem );
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 99;
}
.post-excerpt {
  color: #eee;
  left: 2rem;
  max-width: calc( 100% - 3rem );
  position: absolute;
  top: 3rem;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.featured-image {
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
article:hover .post-title {
  bottom: 2rem;
}
article:hover .post-excerpt {
  color: #111;
}
article.has-featured-image .post-excerpt {
  display: none;
}
article:hover .featured-image {
  opacity: 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_class()` function to insert html classes specific to that post, or, just add a HTML class that contains the post ID. `post_class` will add classes for the post ID, type, etc